# DVD can't play normal commercial purchased DVD movies

Tags: dvd

Just installed Ubuntu on Fujitsu Laptop. Mucic CD plays ok but not DVD. Installed Ubuntu restricted extras and

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
apt-get install regionset
```

But still not able to play just normal bought DVD movie.

VLC does not recognise output/input

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Did you try playing any other videos or another DVD sample just to make sure that the VLC/other player works perfectly.

Comment: try to install libdvdcss2, gstreamer-0.10-plugins-ugly and gstreamer-0.10-plugins-bad, restricted-extras might not be enough.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like libdvdcss2 is missing, libdvd4 also relies on libdvdcss2.

medibuntu used to provide libdvdcss2 but ubuntu restricted extras does not

medibuntu is no more and VLC now packages libdvdcss2

Check your countries laws some do not allow you to install libdvdcss

Since vlc is installed try `sudo apt get install libdvdcss2`

If that fails

Option 2 install the latest libdvdcss2 via a .deb

Here is the AMD 64 .deb http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/libdvdcss-dev_1.2.13-0_amd64.deb

Here is the i386  http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/libdvdcss-dev_1.2.13-0_i386.deb

option 3 go all out and compile vlc from source adding libdvdcss2 and blueray support 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2141949

Comment: Thanks for your help.  ok Option 1 failed. Option 2. Link took me to Ubuntu Software centre .  Error Dependency is not satisfied.

Comment: Took me to Deb Packages and extracted                          libdvdcss-dev_1.2.13-0_amd64.deb.                             Sorry I dont know what to do with it.  new to linux. please advise thanks

Comment: all sorted.  downloaded libdvdcss2_ from debian indexes. Clicking on it took me to the Ubuntu software centre with the option to install.  installed find and dvd now ok.  thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you have it working. Most distributions don't carry libdvdcss due to fears  of running afoul of DMCA style laws.libdvdcss  is a free and open source software library for accessing and unscrambling/decoding DVDs encrypted with the Content Scramble System (CSS). 
For even more informatin about libdvdcss read http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.txt

Comment: Thanks. At least now I understand why there was a problem and your link was interesting and also informative. I really appreciate the help I receive from the forums but its been good to know whys, & hows of the problem and solution. your'e a star.